# Request response over HTTP with Spring and activemq

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am building a simple REST api which connects a web server to a back end service, which performs a simple check and sends a response.

So client (over HTTP) -> to Web Server (over ACTIVEMQ/CAMEL)-> to Checking-Service, and back again.

The endpoint for the GET request is **"/{id}"**. I'm trying to make this send a message through **queue:ws-out** to **queue:cs-in** and map it all the way back again to the original GET request.

The Checking-Service (**cs**) code is fine, it simply changes a value in the CheckMessage object to true using jmslistener.

I've searched the web thoroughly for examples, but can't get anything to work. The closest one I found was the [following](https://codedependents.com/2010/03/04/synchronous-request-response-with-activemq-and-spring/).

This is what I have so far on the Web Server (**ws**).

**RestController**

```
import ...

@RestController
public class RESTController extends Exception{

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String testCamel(@PathVariable String id) {

        //Object used to send out
        CheckMessage outMsg = new CheckMessage(id);
        //Object used to receive response
        CheckMessage inMsg = new CheckMessage(id);

        //Sending the message out (working)
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("ws-out", outMsg);

        //Returning the response to the client (need correlation to the out message"
        return jmsTemplate.receiveSelectedAndConvert("ws-in", ??);
    }

}
```

**Listener on ws**

```
@Service
public class WSListener {

    //For receiving the response from Checking-Service
    @JmsListener(destination = "ws-in")
    public void receiveMessage(CheckMessage response) {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your receive messages from "ws-in" with 2 consumers jmsTemplate.receiveSelectedAndConvert and WSListener !! message from a queue is consumed by one of the 2.
2. you send messages to "ws-out" and consume from "ws-in" ?? last queue
   is empty and not receive any message, you have to send messages to
   it

you need a valid selector to retrieve the message with receiveSelectedAndConvert based on JMSCorrelationID as the example you mntioned or the id received from the rest request but you need to add this id to the message headers like below

```
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("ws-out", id, new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(new CheckMessage(id));
            tm.setJMSCorrelationID(id);
            return tm;
        }
    });


    return jmsTemplate.receiveSelectedAndConvert("ws-in", "JMSCorrelationID='" + id+ "'");
```

forward messages from "ws-out" to "ws-in"

```
@Service
public class WSListener {

    //For receiving the response from Checking-Service
    @JmsListener(destination = "ws-out")
    public void receiveMessage(CheckMessage response) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("ws-in", response);
    }
}
```